# how to use bing search in my angular app.?

Tags: angular, bing-api

I have a Single Page Application, Angular(v5) for front end, how to use bing search in my app.?

I have searched a lot but am failed to find solution.

In [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/call-endpoint-nodejs) available for Node.Js

How can i Integrate this in angular.?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any backend for angular app ?

Comment: yes node(express framework)

Comment: Then you will create your app to consume their req and handle your call with angular app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will directly consume there API from your angular application using `http` API.

Please check the tutorial from [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/core-http-api/) to handle https request in angular.

Please check following snippets for your help,

```
       import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

       //your component method
       doSearch() {

       let subscriptionKey = 'YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION-KEY';
       let customConfigId = 'YOUR-CUSTOM-CONFIG-ID';
       let searchTerm = 'microsoft';

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', subscriptionKey);
        let opts = new RequestOptions();
        opts.headers = headers;

        // here your url
        let url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search?' +
           'q=' + searchTerm +
           '&customconfig=' + customConfigId,

        // http rquest
        this.http.get(url, opts).subscribe(
          res => console.log('handle your response',res.json()),
          msg => console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`)
        );

      }
```

Don't remember exactly, but you can try playing with above snippet.

Otherwise, If you have a `node` in backend then create your own `endpoints` for `Bing Custom Search endpoint` and consumes them in your app using request handler.

Hopes this will help you!!

Comment: from this am getting data, but i want to use [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/hosted-ui)

Comment: you needs to create your own template and bind your methods with it